# Change text in Elementor Menu Cart widget

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce, elementor

How can I change word "Subtotal" and text in "Checkout" and "Show cart" buttons in the new Elementor menu cart widget?
I would like to tranlate them to my language (polish), but these texts are not visible in Loco translate widget that im using. Probably str_ireplace () will work but I can't use it properly. Link to my site - https://www.abreo.pl.

Comment: You need to check "How to edit wordpress template" https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/  and find the exact file to edit

Comment: One more link to some template editing tutorials. https://thethemefoundry.com/blog/edit-wordpress-theme-html/

Comment: Thank you for the comment Mohamed, yes i know i need to edit template, i know how to do this. Problem is with an exact function that will change buttons and text in mentioned widget.

Answer (score 4):

Problem solved...

```
/*Change text strings */
function my_text_strings( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
    switch ( $translated_text ) {
        case 'Subtotal' :
            $translated_text = __( 'Your text here', 'woocommerce' );
            break;
            case 'Checkout' :
            $translated_text = __( 'Your text here', 'woocommerce' );
            break;
            case 'Show Cart' :
            $translated_text = __( 'Your text here', 'woocommerce' );
            break;
    }
    return $translated_text;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'my_text_strings', 20, 3 );
```

Comment: Please share which file, with full path, you have edited for solving this issue. so, in future it will help someone.

Comment: I have same problem so will be nice if you'll say where to add this code :)

Comment: Add this code to your child-theme functions.php file. If you dont have child-theme i strongly recommend to create it, otherwise, after theme update you will lose all changes you made. https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes here you can read about child themes.